# FAILED General metadata correctness test. When using Windows App Certification Kit on my package

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, azure-application-insights, app-certification-kit, wack

I'm using Application Insights in my application. The App runs without any warnings or problems but when I packaged the App and ran a Windows App Certification Kit on it, it failed stating this:

> FAILED General metadata correctness test
>
> •Error Found: The general metadata correctness test detected the
>   following errors:◦The type
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration
>   referenced by type
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.RemoteDependencyModule
>   in file
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.winmd was
>   not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be
>   discoverable. ◦The type
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ISupportConfiguration
>   referenced by type
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.RemoteDependencyModule
>   in file
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.winmd was
>   not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be
>   discoverable.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you use very old Application Insights SDK version. I guess but probably it is 0.14 (The one that you get from VS 2013, this version is not updating any more because packages were renamed). You should remove that SDK version and try the new one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps/
RuntimeTelemetry.winmd  is not there any more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solved it with uninstalling the Application Insights and then reinstalling manually.